# How do I automatically generate a new row in a table when the user signs up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to edit the devise sign up flow so that when a new user signs up I automatically add a row to a specific table with all default values. What is the best way to do this?

Some thought process:

1. Edit the devise registrations_controller - My concern is I will
   then have to do more editing above and beyond what I am trying to
   accomplish.
2. Force a check after the user signs up to see if the row is already 
   there and since they just signed up it won't be and I can add it 
   then... this seems hacky though...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `after_create` callback to your `User` model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    SomeTable.create(user_id: self.id, column1: some_value, column2: some_value.....)
  end
end
```